# instantiating generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IReportRow
{
    List<string> ToList();
}

public interface IReportPreparer<T>
    where T : IReportRow
{
    List<T> GetRows(JObject json);
    string GetAdditionalData(T reportRow);
}
```

a class implementing `IReportRow` interface:

```
public class SellingReportRow : IReportRow
{
  ...interface implementation
}
```

and a class implementing `IReportPreparer` interface:

```
public class SellingReportPreparer : 
IReportPreparer<SellingReportRow>
{
  ...interface implementation
}
```

Now, when I try to make an instance of a SellingReportPreparer class like this:

```
IReportPreparer<IReportRow> preparer = new SellingReportPreparer()
```

Intellisense tells me I need an explicit conversion from `SellingReportPreparer to IReportPreparer< IReportRow >`.

When I convert explicitly like this:

```
IReportPreparer<IReportRow> preparer = (IReportPreparer<IReportRow>)(new SellingReportPreparer());
```

I get an exception - `Unable to cast object of type VSKCasco.ReportPrepare.SellingReportPreparer to type VSKCasco.ReportPrepare.IReportPreparer1[VSKCasco.ReportPrepare.IReportRow]`

I need `IReportPreparer` interface to be generic, so that both its methods would work with the same implementation type of `IReportRow`. How should I make an instance of `SellingReportPreparer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `IReportPreparer` specify its generic parameter as `out`

```
public interface IReportPreparer<out T>
    where T : IReportRow
{
    //List<T> GetRows(JObject json);
    //string GetAdditionalData(T reportRow);
}
```

Then this line will compile

```
IReportPreparer<IReportRow> preparer = new SellingReportPreparer();
```

However, (H/T @GiladGreen), you'll notice I've commented out the line which uses `T` in list - as the list cannot be covariant. If you can get away with being `IEnumerable<T>` then it would work.

```
public interface IReportPreparer<out T>
    where T : IReportRow
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRows(JObject json);
    //string GetAdditionalData(T reportRow);
}
```

Note this time `GetAdditionalData` is still commented out - same problem, no solution!

Comment: will it compile?

Comment: @Jamiec - If you include the lines you put in comment - yes

Comment: @GiladGreen Ah you're right. I didnt pay much attention but `List` cannot be covariant. Well spotted.

Comment: @Jamiec - that's fine :)

Comment: It's not just a problem with `List`, it's also with `string GetAdditionalData(T reportRow);` isn't it?

Comment: @Valentin yes I know - was updating.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the type in

```
public class SellingReportPreparer : 
IReportPreparer<**SellingReportRow**>
{
  ...interface implementation
}
```

needs to be IReportRow like this

```
public class SellingReportPreparer : 
IReportPreparer<IReportRow>
{
  ...interface implementation
}
```

Why the first one doesn't compile:

You're telling SellingReportPreparer to implement IReportPreparer supporting the type SellingReportRow. However, IReportPreparer does not support SellingReportRow, all it knows is IReportRow, and it does not need to know any more than that.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, as this works. I copied all of the OPs code and made this modification and everything works

Comment: Saying "The type needs to be IReportRow" is the complete opposite of the question asked. The OP was asking about covariance (even if they didnt know the word for it!)

Comment: @Jamiec "I need IReportPreparer interface to be generic, so that both its methods would work with the same implementation type of IReportRow.". This answer does not contradict this. That's not the return type, hes telling SellingReportPreparer to implement IReportPreparer<SellingReportRow> which doesn't exist

Comment: @Martin Grégoire Say I have two implementations of IReportRow - class ReportRowA : IReportRow and class ReportRowB : IReportRow. If I use your solution then I could implement SellingReportPreparer in such way that GetRows would return List<ReportRowA> and GetAdditionalData would accept ReportRowB as parameter. I need some restriction so that  both methods would work only with the same implementation.